# Manually activate tabs jquery ui 1.10.3

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I am really getting mad, I searched through jquery ui **doc** and stackoverflow's questions (tons of questions) but I cannot figure out how to **manually activate tabs** ( `.tabs()` ) in jquery 1.10+ .

I founded and tried this solution :

```
$(mytabs).tabs("option", "active", index);
```

but it does not seem to work out. Can someone help me to know how to activate a tab , e.g. when I `create` a new one?

I can't figure out how jQuery UI has no longer the `select` event that , as I could know, accomplished this goal.

I'm creating new `tabs` with this `function` :

```
var addTab = function() {
  var tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#tabs-1'>non titolato</a></li>";
  var li = $.parseHTML(tabTemplate);
    $(li).addClass('ui-corner-all');
    $(".ui-tabs-nav").append(li);
    $("#stepBuilder").tabs('refresh');
}
```

I would like to activate the last one that was created.

Comment: The api documentation is very helpful. http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the following to activate the last tab.

```
$("#stepBuilder").tabs({ active: -1 });
```

I've created [an example for you on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/Wn2Um/).

The [API doc](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) says about the `activate` option:

> `active`
>
> Type: Boolean or Integer
>   Default: 0
>
> Which panel is currently open.
>
> Multiple types supported:
>
> Boolean: Setting active to false will collapse all panels. This requires the collapsible option to be true.
>
> Integer: The zero-based index of the panel that is active (open). A negative value selects panels going backward from the last
>   panel.

Comment: It is working, nice. I am trying to find a way to activate different tabs depending on query. How I can do it? In your example, I can bind this action only on onClick event. How to activate tab on load? Thank you. +1