# Manual tab activation (not on click, but on page load)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tabs

I know there are some threads with same question, but mine is a bit different.

I know how to activate tab on element click. There are many answers about it. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17583129/2898694).

I need to activate tab not on click, but on page load depending on GET query. I am getting param from GET query and then want to activate tab depending on this param.

```
<?
$type = $_GET['type'] ? $_GET['type'] : '0';
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    var type = <?=$type; ?>;

    if(type == 1)
    {
        // activate 1 tab
    } 
    else-if(type == 2)
    {
        // activate 2 tab
    }
    else
    {
        // activate 2 tab
    }
</script>
```

It is just an example.

So the question is: how to use `tabs` method without selector. ~ like there:

```
$.tabs({
    active: type
});
```

(This one not working)

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912762/jquery-ui-tabs-how-to-select-a-tab-based-on-its-id-not-based-on-index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the tabs simply triggering the click action on the desidered tab:

```
$("#tabId").trigger("click");
```

Comment: This doesn't tell OP how to activate the tab on page load.

Comment: @Anon no-no. It helped me. Thank you, Great. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$('#your_tab_id').tabs({ selected: <?php echo $type; ?> });
```

Comment: This will select tab, but on click on `#your_tab_id` element (if other code is fine). I said about it in answer.

Comment: use id mentioned in html. <div id="your_tab_id">

Comment: Yes, I get it. I told you what this code will do. Am I not right?

Comment: your_tab_id is not id of tab content. but the id of wrapping entire div.
I assume you are using Jquery UI Tabs(https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default)